# How to clear the content of textbox in bootstrap-confirmation.js popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

I have gridview. In that gridview i have an Icon. if the icon is clicked then the bootstrap  popover with textbox and two buttons will be opened. 
  If i filled on that textbox of the  popover and then i clicked outside of the  popover, then the  popover will be closed. and then again if i clicked that icon, the popover will be opened.
but the textbox is not empty. the old value is place on that textbox.

Can anyone say, how to empty bootstrap popover textbox, when the popover is opened?

My code is:

```
<img src="Images/icon.png" data-title="Name" data-btnoklabel="Update"
        data-btncancellabel="Cancel" data-textbox="true" data-popout="true"
        runat="server" data-placement="left" data-toggle="confirmation-singleton"
        data-original-title=""
/>
```

Comment: when you click outside the popup to close it , clear all the values of it's textboxes by accessing textboxes `ids`

Comment: can u pls give sample code? because it uses bootstrap-confirmation.js file.

Comment: okay . I am giving you the sample so that you can understand :)

Comment: tnk u so much........

Comment: Try to get know when you click outside to close the popup , which function is actually getting fired . In that function , you can apply my logic .

Comment: where are the API docs for the plugin? It should have callbacks or custom events you can use

Answer (score 0):

1)-Lets suppose you have a function **ClosePopup()** for closing the popup .`

2)-You have two `textboxes` in the popup with ids `txt1` and `txt2`

When function **ClosePopup()** will be fired :-

```
 function ClosePopup(){
     //clear all the values 
     $("#txt1,#txt2").val("");
  }
```

Comment: sorry Tushar Raj.. its not working... this function is not called.